# Rearrange data into a wider format in a specific manner

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

These sample dataframes have data on the two segments of a piecewise regression line. In "df", segment_start is the beginning of the segment, and segment_end is the end of the segment. There is a data point for years 2000-2010. "value" is the slope of the segment. The first segment goes from 2000-2006 and the second from 2007-2010. What I'm trying to do is combine the rows for "obs" 1 into a single row, with all data points, 2000-2010, included, as shown in "df2". Is there a code to automate this process? Thank you for any ideas in advance.

```
#data I have:
df <- tibble("obs" = 1:1, 
             "segment"=c(1,2), 
             "segment_start"=c(2000,2006), 
             "segment_end"=c(2006, 2010),
             "value"=c(0.5, 1.5))

df

#data I want:
df2 <- tibble("obs"=1,
             "2000"=0.5,
             "2001"=0.5,
             "2002"=0.5,
             "2003"=0.5,
             "2004"=0.5,
             "2005"=0.5,
             "2006"=0.5,
             "2007"=1.5,
             "2008"=1.5,
             "2009"=1.5,
             "2010"=1.5)

df2
```

Comment: Do your intervals really overlap by one number? Right now it looks like 2006 is in both groups. How are you deciding where it should go? So you have multiple observations in your full data? Are there possibly more than 2 segments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have non-overlapping regions such as

```
df <- tibble("obs" = 1:1, 
             "segment"=c(1,2), 
             "segment_start"=c(2000, 2007), 
             "segment_end"=c(2006, 2010),
             "value"=c(0.5, 1.5))
```

Then you can use `rowise` with `mutate()` to create a sequence for each row. Then ou use `tidyr::unnest_longer` to expand those into rows. Finally you use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to turn those rows into columns

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(year = list(segment_start:segment_end)) %>% 
  unnest_longer(year) %>% 
  pivot_wider(obs, names_from=year, values_from=value)
```

It's just important to be consistent about the start/ends and whether or not each interval end value is open or closed.

Comment: This worked nicely, thank you! I adjusted the segment start of the second segment to eliminate the overlap as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the original dataframe, the expected output can be done with `complete` + `fill` + `pivot_wider`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  complete(segment_start = full_seq(c(min(segment_start), max(segment_end)), 1)) %>% 
  fill(obs, segment, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(-c(segment, segment_end), names_from = segment_start)

# A tibble: 1 x 12
    obs `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010`
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
```